# (this) not works in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have ts script
Here is code of it

```
window.customRadio = function(radioName) {
    const radioButton = $(`input[type=radio][name='${radioName}']`);
    $(radioButton).each(function() {
        $(this).wrap(`<span class='custom-radio-${radioName.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '')}'></span>`);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        }
    });

    return $(radioButton).click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        }

        return $(radioButton).not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
        });
    });
};
```

But in this row I have error `return $(radioButton).not(this).each(function() {`

Here is error message

> Argument of type 'TElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>     Type 'Node' is not assignable to type 'JQuery'.
>       Property 'ajaxComplete' is missing in type 'Node'.

How I can solve it?

Comment: so you are trying to change your `radioButton` on click but you've set it to a constant?

Comment: You've tagged TypeScript, and the error is clearly from TypeScript, but I don't see any type annotations in the code...?

Comment: okay. const is killing it?@ZombieChowder

Comment: No, `const` is not the problem.

Comment: What code, specifically, does the error point to?

Comment: let is not helping @BelminBedak

Comment: I mark code in what I have error@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @eugene: *Specifically* -- which part of that line? (TypeScript does tell you, I believe; if not, move each part to a separate line.) (Meanwhile, you're just ignoring the question about the absense of any type annotations?)

Comment: I can see that the quotes are not properly used here `$(this).wrap(`<span class='custom-radio-${radioName.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '')}'></span>`);` Since you are using single quotes, this section ``<span class=` is not counted as a piece of the string.

Comment: @ZombieChowder: No, that line's fine. It's tricky, but the single quotes you're referring to are within a token (`${...}`) in the template literal. It's fine. ([In action here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmuLxweL/).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this one .not(this). About type of what are you talking?

Comment: You're using TypeScript. The only reason for using TypeScript is type safety. To have type safety, you need type annotations. Your code is just JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess I shouldn't consider dropping Farsight Soft. an email regarding any junior positions lol.

Comment: Okay. you talk about type of radioButton variable?@T.J.Crowder

Comment: No. TypeScript believes `this` is of type `TElement`. But jQuery's `not` only accepts strings, elements, functions, arrays, and jQuery instances. So you need to ensure that you add any necessary type annotations to tell TypeScript what `this` is in the context where you're using it. (Given the code above, I'm a bit surprised you have to.) I don't know precisely how you do that above (not being into TypeScript much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Intall @types/jquery, if not installed.
2. Add interface Window{customRadio:()=>JQuery} into separate file, without any imports/exports.
3. Show the place where you are using "ajaxComplete" method

Comment: 1)types are installed
2) I added `interface Window { 
    load_autocomplete_fields: any;
    load_datepickers :any;
    load_datepickers_inline:any; 
    customCheckbox:any;
    customCheckboxes:any;
    customRadio:any;
  }`
into same file. so my custom window.**** are working

3) ajaxComplete?

Comment: If i add `customRadio:()=>JQuery` I have error
`Type '(radioName: any) => JQuery<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type '() => JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

Comment: Yes make it (radioName:string) => jQuery

Comment: Okay, solved it with `customRadio:(radioName)=>JQuery;`

Comment: Where do you have a code for this errors "Property 'ajaxComplete' is missing in type 'Node'."?  It means that somewhere script returns Node and not  JQuery. But in you function everything seems to be fine.

Comment: But have trouble here 

`return $(radioButton).not(this).each(function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
  });`

Comment: In `.not(this)`

Comment: Try not $(this), JQuery.not types returns same type as input. And this is an element. 
So you need to use (radioButtons.not(this) as JQuery),
or radiButtons.not($(this))

Comment: Seems it helps. Thank's